# Using Unordered Text Features in Machine Learning Model

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, text-mining, data-preprocessing

I am building a classification model using deidentified patient data with ICD-10 codes as inputs. Each code is a string and represents a diagnosis, and these follow the pattern of 1 letter, followed by 2 digits, followed by numbers and/or letters. However, patients can have multiple associated ICD-10 codes, so I am not sure how to handle this. There are some logical groupings, though, and the initial letter of the code represents a general category of diagnoses (e.g. cardiovascular).

A patient may have multiple ICD-10 codes. For instance, if a patient has hypertension and diabetes, this may be I1310 and E119.

My naive approach would be to make, say, 10 columns for each patient [diagnosis 1, diagnosis 2, etc.] and use that as training data. However, this has the issue that, for instance, even if two patients both have diabetes, patient A may have this as diagnosis 2 but patient B may have this as diagnosis 4. I am assuming this would hinder the model from training properly.
I'm not sure if one-hot encoding is appropriate either; OHE would drastically increase the time complexity of the algorithm since there are more than 100,000 unique ICD codes recorded in the dataset.

Any thoughts on how to approach this problem?